# Compose key, multiple layouts

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome. I tend to jump between keyboard layouts (namely US and DA).

I'd like to be able to input accented characters using the american keyboard layout. To this end I can enable the Compose Key, but enabling the compose key breaks the behaviour of the compose key under the danish layout. Does anyone have a workaround to this/active bug-report reference?

I can of course choose a different compose key from Right-Alt, but that feels very unnatural (as well as taking away from me a valuable key I could use for other things). So more specifically, I'd like a workaround that allows me to use Right-Alt as the compose key.

Comment: Did you choose <Right Alt> as the compose key? You can use some other key, e.g. <Right Ctrl>.

Comment: Yes, you're right that is a possible work-around. Let me update the question to reflect this.

Comment: It's not a workaround. If you pick a key as a compose key, that key's other functionality is overridden by design. Also, an alternative way to input accented characters is to use _English (US, international with dead keys)_ instead of _English (US)_.

Comment: Was not aware of this option. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: None of these solution quite fit my taste. Guess I'll just stick with jumping between layouts as I go. Thanks for the help anyways. Must say that it's unfortunate that you have to disable to the compose key in one layout to use it in another. Perhaps a better design would be to have per-language compose key options.

Comment: The intl layout with*out* dead keys is the one I want, but the compose key doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Typically you don't need a compose key with that layout to type the most common accented characters. It might be easier to help if you let us know which accented characters you need to be able to type with the English layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68495/discussion-between-fredefox-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Answer (score 0):

you could use the capslock key as compose key to my knowledge that ones function should be consistent across layouts

tho then you'll have use your shift key to input capital letter which i hope isn't too much of an hassle